# How to implement Crypto chart widget with Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, cryptocurrency, coinmarketcap

I need to implement crypto chart widget for every coin in my application, it's based on [coinmarketcap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com) home page, I couldn't find any topic that how to implement it. So far this is what I did and on Last 7 Days column I want to place the chart widget for every coin.

I am using Angular 11 with TypeScript.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a **charting library** for Angular. It looks like someone has created a decent wrapper for [Google Charts](https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts).

The graphs on `coinmarketcap.com` are pre-rendered images, so an alternative approach you could take is creating these images beforehand (something that could be done on the server side with Google Charts or another charting library) and serving them in the chart column.